# Syntax Issues while using []

Tags: php, syntax

So while working on a test project (learning purpose) I found that its possible to use syntax like:

> throw new Exception($Query->errorInfo()[2]);

notice use of [2] (array index) after $Query->errorInfo().

This thing also seems to be working on other functions like explode;

since when? and/or what kind of specific environment is required for this to work? because it seems to be working fine on my web server but not on my localhost xampp installation.

also it also seems to be possible to define arrays by simply setting $var = [2, 4, 5];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PHP 5.4.0 as you can see the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

```
Short array syntax has been added, e.g. $a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
or $a = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4];.
```

---

```
Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].
```

Comment: is it possible to use a class-driven or static function as argument in another user defined function?

public function ($arg1, $arg2 = $this->stamp()) {

Comment: You can explicitly use object as type of the argument, but not a method. `public function method1 ($arg1, MyClass $arg2)` or, the one you want to achieve, will happen in the definition, not in the arguments: `public function method1 ($arg1, $arg2 = null) { if ($arg2 == null) {$arg2 = $this->stamp() } //continue method defintion; }`

Comment: there you do, you got my vote! and by the way yes I tried the $arg2=null with is_null comparsion.